# Docker capture packets

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I have a docker host with 3 containers running 3 different apps.

I'd like to install Suricata (IDS) / tcpdump on the host itself, to be able to:
 1. Capture packets from a container and outside.
 2. Capture packets between 2 containers.

Are 2 options possible?  What is the procedure to get my goals?

Thanks!!!